# Отображение куки в chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, cookie, google-chrome-devtools

Ситуация, описанная ниже, повторяется для многих сервисов. Для конкретики я опишу, например, работу с сервисами яндекс.

1. Логинюсь на почту mail.yandex.ru
2. Захожу на другой домен. Например, ya.ru. В инспекторе хрома отображается куки с домена yandex.ru.
   [image: Куки]
3. Удаляю куку Session_id.
4. Возвращаюсь на вкладку с почтой яндекса, и обнаруживаю, что моя сессия закончилась, и меня выкинуло на форму авторизации.

Вопрос: почему на домене ya.ru отображаются куки с домена yandex.ru?
Когда я чищу куки на текущем сайте, я вовсе не хочу, чтобы у меня слетали сессии на других сайтах.

Comment: В третьем столбце прямым текстом написано, что это кука с yandex.ru. Так что разлогин логичен.

Comment: Правильный вопрос: почему тут видно эту куку? Потому что инспектор показывает куки всех доменов на которые были запросы с данной страницы

Comment: Ну и наконец, а зачем её удалять?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Для меня было не очевидно, что хром показывает куки всех доменов, на которые были запросы с текущего сайта. Файрфокс, например, так не делает - там показываются куки только текущего домена.

Comment: По поводу удаления куки. Иногда мне нужно удалить куки сайта, чтобы проверить, что мой код для этого сайта корректно работает. И когда я удаляю все куки (или нажимаю кнопку clear site data в пункте clear storage), то удаляются и те куки, которые я хотел бы сохранить (с другого домена).